# How to make a screen not fall asleep if the app runs on boot?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have the app which must start on device' boot. It works well but the problem is that when the app finishes booting, the screen is already dark. How can I make it not fall asleep? 
My Receiver:

```
<receiver
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true"
      android:name=".view.receivers.BootReceiver"
      android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  private final static String LOG_TAG = BootReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
      Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Loading after booting...");
      Intent startCalendarActivityIntent = new Intent(context, CalendarActivity.class);
      startCalendarActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(startCalendarActivityIntent);
    } else {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error while restarting after boot.");
    }
  }
}
```

On this device is Android 6.0 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use [wakelocks](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html), which need certain permissions, or you can put a flag in your onCreate method, which according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) does not require a permission.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

The wakelock documentation gave the example above.